# Can I reference a specific column in a remote table (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, mysql-workbench, remote

I have two databases (MySQL) on two different servers, and one table references a table in the other. However, I am unable to point the reference to a specific column in the remote table for some reason. Can someone help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.foo, b.bar
    FROM db1.tableA AS a
    JOIN db2.tableB AS b  ON a.something = b.whatever;
```

This assumes both "databases" are on the same instance of MySQL on the same server.  Otherwise, you need to reword the question.

Comment: I edited the question... they are on different servers.
On the note of same servers, however, I am also trying to figure out MySQL Workbench. Is there a way to perform such a join (same server this time) on specific columns from tables in different databases directly within Workbench? 
Thank you!

Comment: For different servers...  See `FEDERATED` or `Spider` engines.  Or make separate connections in your code and simulate the `JOIN`.